# Pull URL parameters into a WordPress "Raw HTML" content element

Tags: wordpress, url-parameters

I'm using the URL Params plugin to pull parameters into regular content using a short code. But I have to use a Raw HTML block to insert Typeform code into the page and I want to be able to pass a URL parameter into the Typeform code to track the source of the form submission.

I can't figure out how to do it. The form is working fine at: https://HelloExit.com/instant-valuation

But I want to be able to send people to https://HelloExit.com/instant-valuation/?source=XXXX and pull the XXXX into the Typeform code as the "source" value in the "data-url"

Here's what I tried:

```html
<script>
  function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }
  var source = getUrlVars()["source"];
</script>
    
<div
  class="typeform-widget"
  data-url="https://xgenius.typeform.com/to/zZHPPk?source=<script>document.write(source)</script>"
  data-transparency="100"
  data-hide-headers=true
  data-hide-footer=true
  style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
</div>
    
<!-- Typeform embed code -->
<script>(function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, 
ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", 
b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)) { js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; 
js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() 
</script><div style="font-family: Sans-Serif;font-size: 12px;color: #999;opacity: 0.5;padding-top: 5px;"> powered by <a href="https://admin.typeform.com/signup?utm_campaign=zZHPPk&utm_source=typeform.com-01D8JVB4T91A26RA6WEZRZVF05- pro&utm_medium=typeform&utm_content=typeform-embedded-poweredbytypeform&utm_term=EN" style="color: #999" target="_blank">Typeform</a></div>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but you'll need to use Javascript to alter the `data-url` attribute of your div.

```js
// ...
var source = getUrlVars()["source"];

// concatenate the url with your source variable
var newUrl = `https://xgenius.typeform.com/to/zZHPPk?source=${source}`;

// get the element whose attributes you want to dynamically set
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
var widgetElement = document.querySelector('.typeform-widget');

// set the source attribute
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute
widgetElement.setAttribute('data-url', newUrl);
```

Test this carefully, as it might still end up with a race condition (that is, the Typeform embed code might start running before you've updated the `data-url` attribute that it references).

Comment: Totally works! The view source shows the hard-coded URL, but in the background it's working. Thank you, Simmer!!

Comment: Great! btw, `View Source` always will show the original HTML. To get a view into attributes after they've been dynamically altered, try right-clicking on the element in question and choosing `Inspect Element`.